# gtkmm + glade? (create combo box text + entery box)

Tags: c++, windows, gtk, glade, gtkmm3

Welcome colleagues. Do GUI for your application. By using glade + gtkmm. I do not understand how it is possible to specify the size of objects: combo box text and text entery. I change the size in the common menu, but nothing happens. Is there any way to solve it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3aHg.png

Answer (score 0):

GTK+ has a different approach to most GUI toolkits. It uses the space available and recalculates sizes automatically with the size of the parent. Most GUI toolkits make them fixed and leaves it to the coder to resize them. Some GUI toolkits are moving toward the GTK+ model for a variety of reasons.

You can, however, play with the tab expand and tab fill settings of GtkGrid to give it a fixed size or place them in a GtkFixed container if that's what you really want. Personally, I prefer to just go with it.

Comment: It uses GtkFixed, but it does not solve the problem or you propose to allocate a new block GtkFixed?

http://i.imgur.com/ltFRyb8.png

Comment: Putting all the controls in a GTKFixed container should mean that the width request and height requests (in the common attributes of each control) are honored. For the GtkCompletion, you can specify a GtkCellArea which should (I've never tried it) restrict the size of the popup. The version of Glade I'm using doesn't seem to allow their creation, though, so you may have to add it programmatically.

Comment: Сombo box text is obtained from large text, but does not accept text entery larger. Maybe it can be done programmatically?

P,S: What function gtkmm loads projects Glade?

Comment: Gtk::Builder::create_from_file loads the glade file. Are you asking about the size of the font, the size of the popup or the size of the contents of the text entry? You can create a larger text box by specifying the common property "width in chars" in glade but it's not supposed to resize to the largest possible entry.